# Setting up a SQL Database on an IIS7 Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, database

I have a server running IIS7, and Ii want to set up an SQL database on it to use with my web application.  I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289230/openning-sql-connection-from-iis7) and I'm very new to this so I'm a bit lost as what to do.
can somebody please give me some pointers as to how to go about doing this.
CHEERS

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?  Install MS SQL?

Comment: Basically i'm trying to connect to an sql database hosted on the same machine as the iis server using the same connection string that worked when running it in VS (using integrated security). I think it must have something to do with permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make sure the Identity of your Application Pool (account your application pools runs as) has access to the database since you want to use integrated security.